# Protocol to be used with in jar file

Tags: java

I have to make a call from my java code to some other classes that is within jar file .So which protocol it is going to use .

Regards,
Raj

Comment: Protocols? You don't need any protocol, just import that classes and call them as you would do with any other class

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by protocol? a jar is an ordinary zip file. You just need to include the jar in your classpath and you are good to go.

Comment: What if within jar file calling some mq ,so is it requires any other protocl?

Answer (score 2):

It does not need any protocol. The class file inside the Jar would be accessed directly just like any other class on your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a run-able jar which contains runnable program with  main class just use

java -jar < your jar file here >(if you want to run it)

otherwise import it to your project.(not sure what you mean by mentioning  about a protocol)

Comment: because you mentioned mq notsure if [this](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wci/v6r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.cast_iron.doc%2FMQ_installing_jarfiles.html) helps,
but still not sure about the protocol part. I think that although a protocol is used it doesn't have to do with the use of the jar file.

Comment: (eg communication between enclosed code rather than the jar, so the jar is still a kind of zip)